# Arduino ADK Blink example not blinking sometimes

Tags: arduino

I have arduino uno connected with itead usbshield. I am receiving the data from android phone and it blinks only when i open serial monitor otherwise it is not. How to blink it independently. Is there any way it relates with opening serial monitor...?

I use pin 13 for blinking it...
Please guide me in to this...

This is the code..

```
void loop()
{
Usb.Task();
if(adk.isReady()) {
uint8_t msg[1];
uint16_t len = sizeof(msg);
uint8_t rcode = adk.RcvData(&len, msg);
if(rcode && rcode != hrNAK)
  USBTRACE2("Data rcv. :", rcode);
  if(len > 0) {
  Serial.print(F("\r\nData Packet: "));
  Serial.print(msg[0]);
  digitalWrite(LED,msg[0] ? HIGH : LOW);
  }
}
else
digitalWrite(LED, LOW);
}
```

Regards
Vinod

Answer (score 0):

To which pin is the LED connected? My guess is that it is connected to pin 13

Pin 13 is also wired to the serial port. When ever there is any data transmission happening in the serial port, pin 13 is wired to blink.